# How do I create a user control view in MVC3, create events and reuse it in other views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3.  In asp.net user control, its fairly easy to create a user control that has a combo box with a button, with hover over event, and a collection property of combo box that then displays a list

how do i achieve this user control (partial view) in mvc3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is helper methods.  You can see a good explanation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988945/asp-net-mvc-custom-controls).  In that post, there is a great link for how to do this: [Creating Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).

I am also a WebForms developer originally, and I had a hard time making the connection between user controls and HTML Helpers.  This should give you enough guidance to get started with what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, I am looking for helper methods

Answer (score 0):

Hover over event can be done using jQuery, your combo box just needs to have a CSS class in the partial view and then the even can be hooked up to that selector.

The Collection property will be inside the View Model that your partial view binds to.